# Is there a way to visualise a query in a kanban style board view?

Tags: azure-devops

In my organization, our Azure DevOps setup has individual projects for individual areas. We have several areas in the 'digital' space and we need to be able to track activity and prioritize across these projects together.

So far we've managed to set up cross-project queries which are working reasonably well, but we want to visualize the work items in a kanban style board.

I've found an extension that shows a query in a board view but it hasn't been updated for some time and doesn't fully solve our issue (it's not listing the cards in priority order). https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards

Is there another option?

Thanks
Callum

Comment: Don't really have an answer, sorry, but have a similar question with a reference to yours: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8590/kanban-board-customising-number-of-fields-displayed-on-the-board-items-for-indi

Comment: It is not supported. You can deploy a extension to do it (as the Query based boards extension)